# Java の "java.xml cannot be resolved to a module" のエラーを取りたいです．

Tags: java, eclipse

普段めったにJavaやEclipseに触らないのですが、使用しているフレームワークを動かすとお客さんのところでSaxのエラーが検出されてしまい、仕方がないので、フレームワークの特定バージョンをソースから落として修正し.jarを自分でビルドしようとしています．

1. 落としたもの
   https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot/releases/tag/3.4.1 のSource code (zip)
2. プロジェクトを作る手順
   Eclipse（2020-09）で、dita-ot-3.4.1\src\mainにプロジェクトを、設定．ビルドしたいのはmain\javaのフォルダのみです．
3. 同じフレームワークのバイナリ配布から、ライブラリを以下のように参照します．JRE System Libraryとして、jre 1.8.0_261を使用しています．
   [image: ライブラリ参照設定]

これで、javaフォルダのエラーはほとんど取れますが、module-info.javaの`requires java.desktop;`と`requires java.xml;`だけエラーが取れません．"java.xml cannot be resolved to a module", "java.desktop cannot be resolved to a module"のエラーになります．ソースは以下のようなものです．

```
module main {
    exports org.ditang.relaxng.defaults;
    exports com.idiominc.ws.opentopic.fo.index2.util;
    exports org.dita.dost.module.filter;
    exports com.idiominc.ws.opentopic.xsl.extension;
    exports org.dita.dost.ant.types;
    exports com.renderx.xep;
    exports com.renderx.xep.lib;
    exports org.dita.dost;
    exports org.dita.dost.module;
    exports org.dita.dost.platform;
    exports org.dita.dost.invoker;
    exports org.dita.dost.pipeline;
    exports com.renderx.util;
    exports org.dita.dost.ant;
    exports org.dita.dost.exception;
    exports org.dita.dost.project;
    exports org.dita.dost.pdf2;
    exports org.dita.dost.module.reader;
    exports com.idiominc.ws.opentopic.fo.xep;
    exports com.idiominc.ws.opentopic.fo.index2;
    exports org.dita.dost.util;
    exports org.dita.dost.index;
    exports org.dita.dost.writer;
    exports com.suite.sol.ditaot;
    exports org.dita.dost.reader;
    exports com.idiominc.ws.opentopic.fo.index2.configuration;
    exports com.idiominc.ws.opentopic.fo.i18n;
    exports org.dita.dost.log;
    exports org.dita.dost.module.saxon;

    requires java.desktop;
    requires java.xml;
}
```

もし分かる方おられましたらよろしくお願いいたします．

以上

[image: module-info.javaの画面]

（追記）
このやり方は昔のこのフレームワークをビルドしていた時のやり方でした、（昔は何も考えずにこれでビルド出来た）

@Kohei さんの回答を見ていませんでしたが、よくよく調べて試行錯誤の結果、dita-ot-3.4.1/gradlew.batを実行すればなんの問題もなくビルド出来ました．失礼いたしました．

[image: gradle.batによるビルド]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ビルドしてjarファイルを作成するのが目標ですよね？

であれば、[READMEに書いてある通り](https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot#for-developers)、以下の手順でビルドできます。

1. DITA-OTのGitリポジトリーをクローン:

   ```
   git clone git://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot.git
   ```
2. dita-otディレクトリーに移動:

   ```
   cd dita-ot
   ```
3. サブモジュールをフェッチ:

   ```
   git submodule update --init --recursive
   ```
4. gradlewを実行:

   ```
   ./gradlew
   ```

※バージョン3.4.1を修正したいのであれば、`gradlew`の前に`git checkout`でmasterから3.4.1に変更する必要があります。

「普段めったにJavaやEclipseに触らない」方がソースコードを修正したいということでしたら、EclipseよりもIntelliJでプロジェクトを開いた方が簡単かなぁと思います。

Comment: 「gradlewを実行」⇒まさにそのとおりでした．バージョン3.4.1は最初に書きましたがGitに紐づけずにソースのZIPでそのまま落とせます．